# Why am I getting an object required error when trying to get user input for the name of a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I'm trying to insert formulas into my worksheet, but my first and second attempts haven't gone so well.

So, first I thought it would be better to use the GetOpenFilename feature for accuracy's sake, rather than having the user input the name of the workbook themselves. I used [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26471209/9686996) while writing it. When I run the code, the Open dialogue box opens, but when I select a workbook I keep getting a:

> "Runtime Error '424': object required".

I'm not sure what it's asking for? At first I had just `Application.GetOpenFilename()`, so I thought I needed to add the filter, but it didn't help.

```
    Sub openfile()

Dim mainwb As Workbook
Set mainwb = Application.GetOpenFilename("Microsoft Excel Files, *.xls*")

Dim mainws As Worksheet
mainws = InputBox("Please enter the name of the worksheet")

Dim rdsMonthly As Variant
rdsMonthly = InputBox("Please insert current month column in format $A:$A")

Dim rdsID As Variant
rdsID = InputBox("Please insert ID column in format $A:$A")

Cells(8, 14) = "=IFERROR(SUMIFS('[" & mainwb & "]" & mainws & "'!" & rdsMonthly & ", '[" & mainwb & "]" & mainws & "'!" & rdsID & ", $C55), " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"


End Sub
```

After, I tried using an Input box instead

```
 Dim mainwb As Workbook
mainwb = InputBox("Please enter the name of the workbook, including file extension")
```

But that's giving me a:

> "Runtime error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set".

I have no idea what it wants from me, and I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the name of the workbook, indicated with `.GetOpenFileName`, you may split once the big string through `/` and then get the last item. Then, split again by `.xls` and take the 0th item. With 1 line this 2 operations look like this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Microsoft Excel Files, *.xls*")

    Dim nameOfWb As String
    'do not do this at production, but split it to variables:
    nameOfWb = Split(Split(filePath, "\")(UBound(Split(filePath, "\"))), ".xls")(0)
    Debug.Print nameOfWb

End Sub
```

---

`Application.GetOpenFilename("Microsoft Excel Files, *.xls*")` returns a string of the workbook path. And `Workbooks()` needs a workbook name, which is already opened.

Try this:

```
Sub TestMe()

  Dim mainwb As Workbook
  Set mainwb = Workbooks.Open(Application.GetOpenFilename("Microsoft Excel Files, *.xls*"))

  MsgBox mainwb.Name

End Sub
```

- [Application.GetOpenFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename)

Comment: I'd like to avoid actually opening that workbook if possible, it's pretty huge. I just want to use the name in a formula.

Comment: @Sylphie - I understand. I have udpated.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the "Dim as workbook" was the problem.